# How to browse a network with mono.upnp

Tags: c#, mono

How can I browse the current devices on my network with [mono.upnp](https://github.com/mono/mono-upnp)?

There is zero documentation and my "best guess":

```
bool keepalive = true;
Task.Run(() =>{
    using (var client = new Client())
    {                    
        client.ServiceAdded += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine($"Added: {a.Service}");
        client.DeviceAdded += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine($"Added: {a.Device}");

        client.BrowseAll();

        while (keepalive) Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
});

Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit");
Console.ReadLine();
keepalive = false;
```

... doesn't do anything. Most of the unit tests in the project appear to create a device/service after the client is created. but I don't see anything that interrogates the network. I had a look at the internal memory of `client` after I called `BrowseAll` and it changed nothing. My firewall is off --before then it asked for permission which I gave-- and via a separate upnp browser, I can see a windows media server from another machine, and I only see one network adapter.